# Avoid nested objects when using nested serializers

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two models, one contains the other in a foreignKey relationship, I wanted to make an API that would return the combine of these two models, so I attempted to use nested Serializers to add the related model as well, but the data are not all on the same level, the related models is a object inside the first.

Here are the Models

```py
class ModelOne(models.Model):
    last_counter = models.IntegerField()


class ModelTwo(models.Model):
    model_one = models.ForeignKey(ModelOne, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    counter_type = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

Here are the serializers

```py
class ModelOneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelOne
        fields = "__all__"


class ModelTwoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model_one= ModelOneSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ModelTwo
        fields = "__all__"
```

This would return from the API in the form of

```
{
   "category" : ...,
   "counter_type" : ...,
   "model_one" : {
     "last_counter" : ...
   }
}
```

But I **don't** want the response to be like that, I want it more like this

```
{
   "category" : ...,
   "counter_type" : ...,
   "last_counter" : ...,
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this through serializers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SerializerMethodField`

```
from rest_framework.fields import SerializerMethodField

class ModelTwoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    last_counter = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = ModelTwo
        fields = "__all__"

    def get_last_counter(self, obj):
        return ModelOneSerializer(obj.model_one).data['last_counter']
```

When creating custom fields(`field_one` for example) with `SerializerMethodField`, you have to create a method called `get_field_one`, for this method to be automatically detected by the serializer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this works when the **ModelOne** only has one field, how would i bring all the fields in **ModelOne**, would i have to make a separate field for each field in ModelOne?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, that's how it works. I often use the method that you came up with at first. Yes, it introduces the next level of nesting of data but it works with just a few lines of code that can be easily maintained in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want to do using SerializerMethodField from drf fields:

SerializerMethodField is a read-only field that computes its value at request processing time, by calling a method on the serializer class it is attached to. For example for your case it will look like this. Notice that the computed last_counter is added on the serialized model fields.

```
from rest_framework.fields import SerializerMethodField

class ModelTwoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    last_counter = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

class Meta:
    model = ModelTwo
    fields = ["category", "counter_type", "last_counter"]

def get_last_counter(self, obj):
    return int(obj.model_one.last_counter)
```

SerializerMethodField accepts method_name, but it’s usually more convenient to use the default pattern for naming those methods, which is get_. Just make sure you‘re not overburdening your method fields with any heavy-lifting operations.

You can read more on the official documentation:[enter link description here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)